# How can I link Nodes of two different types? (templated classes)

Tags: c++, templates, nodes

I'm making a templated class that consists of two binary search trees that are linked together.
For example, a tree of strings and a tree of ints.

However, I'm having trouble with creating the link.

What I have for the nodes:

```
template <class T>
class Node {

T data;
Node* link;
Node* left;
Node* right;

}
```

if I call

```
Node<string> newstring = new Node<string>();
Node<int> newint = new Node<int>();
newstring -> link = newint;
newint -> link = newstring;
```

i'll get

```
error: cannot convert ‘Node<int>*’ to ‘Node<std::basic_string<char> >*
error: cannot convert ‘Node<std::basic_string<char> >* to ‘Node<int>*’
```

How can I link Nodes of two different types?

Comment: The real question is "Why do you want to do that ?" It looks like a design problem of your code.

Comment: First think that Node should contain some data, not only links. Then your question will be somewhat different.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by a base class:

```
class BaseNode {
};

template <class T>
class Node : public BaseNode {
public:
    BaseNode * link;
    BaseNode * left;
    BaseNode * right;
};
```

and then

```
Node<string> * newstring = new Node<string>();
Node<int> * newint = new Node<int>();
newstring -> link = newint;
newint -> link = newstring;
```

Maybe you need to add some code to identify what is the real type of the pointer points to. It should be a design problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'll look into base classes.

It looks like the design for Node is faulty.
I might do something like

```
template <class T, class S>
class Node {

T data;
Node<S,T>* link;
Node<T,S>* left;
Node<T,S>* right;

}
```